# How to link ALU to registers, RAM and Clock?

Tags: microcontroller, cpu, alu

I've designed a basic 4-Bit ALU which computes A+B, A-B, B-A, and a few logic operations. I'm using a mux to determine which output appears at the multiplexer output. This is a basic start to a CPU as far as I understand.. where do I now go from here? How do I link it to the RAM (will be a small array of D-Type flip-flops) and the Clock? Which basic registers do I fundamentally need?

I'm a little confused as to how the components of the most utterly basic CPU components interface together and where/when/how the data travels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've built a 4-bit ALU, I'm going to assume you're interested in building a 4-bit computer.  It will be almost half the work of building a 8-bit one, since the busses will be half as wide.

The following diagram is from a paper titled "[A Simple and Affordable TTL Processor for the Classroom](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1595&context=compsci)".  It describes in quite a bit of detail the architecture of a 4-bit computer called CHUMP ("Cheap Homebrew Understandable Minimal Processor").

It is a [Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture), meaning the program and data are in separate memories (program ROM and RAM in the diagram).  It uses a single accumulator register (Accum), rather than the register arrays typically found in microcontrollers today.

[image]

PC is program counter which holds the address of the next instruction in the program ROM.  The control ROM is used to decode the instructions.  Each CHUMP instruction uses a 4-bit opcode (maximum of 16 instructions) and a 4-bit operand.  This means it can load only one nibble of immediate data (0-F), address 16 RAM locations, perhaps 16 I/O ports, and be limited to 16 instructions.  But these limitations will make it easier to build.  You'll still need 64 FF's for your RAM.

You pretty much need to have all of the blocks shown above.  If you are going to be making very small programs, you could use some sort of 16 x 4 plugboard instead of using EPROMs.  Perhaps you could use a solderless breadboard.  [This one](http://ep.yimg.com/ca/I/yhst-27389313707334_2252_92762545) with 30 rows could store 14 instructions (7x4 on each side). Storing programs in RAM ("[Von Neumann architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture)") would be problematic since you would have to have a way of loading the program into RAM anyway.

Here are how the busses (all 4-bit) are wired.  The output of the PC selects the address in program ROM. The input to the PC comes from the instruction operand in ROM (Sel Mux=0).  This same path can be used to load an address from the instruction operand into the Addr latch, which selects a nibble from RAM.  The RAM is read into the ALU from RAM with Sel Mux=1, or from the Program ROM (Sel Mux=0) as a constant literal.  The Accum (accumulator) can be go to either the other side of the ALU, or be written into RAM.  There is also a path to load either the PC or Addr latch from RAM, but I don't know if that's used.

Instructions are executed in several cycles, the advancing of the cycles is done using the system clock.

- First the first nibble of the instruction containing the opcode is
  fetched from the program ROM.  (As mentioned before, each instruction
  is two nibbles long, a 4-bit opcode and a 4-bit operand.)
- Next decode the opcode (shown as control ROM in the block diagram;
  this is misleading, you can do it just with logic).
- Read the second nibble of the instruction, which will be either an
  address in program ROM, a constant (literal) in program ROM, or an
  address in RAM.
- Execute the decoded instruction.

If the PC is not loaded from the instruction operand (jump instruction), then it is incremented after every instruction.

I suggest running your clock very slow, maybe only 1 MHz or so, so you can easily trace the operation using an oscilloscope.  You probably want to add a single-step feature also, which executes one instruction per button push.  Lots of blinking LEDs connected to the PC, Addr latch, and accumulator are good too.

Here is a page which has [links to six other 4-bit computer pages](http://www.ttlcpu.com/tags/4-bit-cpus), many with schematics.  And here are [two](http://www.bigmessowires.com/nibbler/) [more](http://jaromir.xf.cz/fourbit/fourbit.html), which weren't on the list above.

Answer (score 1):

Just about every CPU will have an accumulator register to store one operand (and the result) of a math operation. You'll also need at least one other general purpose register for the other operand. From there, it depends on how much functionality you want to build in: you'll probably want another general purpose register for temporary storage, and if you want to access memory, you should have register(s) to store the addresses. You might look into the 6502 processor for an example of a simple register design (that is nonetheless very efficient), and the Z80 for an example of a much more complex design.

To interface with RAM, you'll need an address bus and a data bus. These account for most of the pins on a typical CPU: for example, to address 64k of memory holding 1 byte each, you need 16 address pins and 8 data pins (unless you work for Intel, in which case you probably kludge it to use 12 pins total, and drive the people who use your chip to drink :) You'll also need some way to enable the RAM (i.e. chip select) and set it to read or write; look at the data sheets for typical RAM chips and get to know the pinouts.

For the clock, you'll need an input for the signal itself; you might want to have an output, too, since the purpose of the clock is to sychronize all the chips. You'll have to change your design to implement the fetch/decode/execute cycle in time with the clock signal: that's beyond my understanding, but any good book on digital design should tell you how.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may look for diagrams about classical 8-bits CPUs, for example :

http://www.msxarchive.nl/pub/msx/mirrors/msx2.com/zaks/z80prg02.htm

They are generally organised around a few shared busses, where the registers are connected. There is a sequencer that selects for each cycle of each instruction how the muxes are selected, which registers are updated....